# Storing date values in an array

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am writing a code in Asp.Net using VB (and yup it's my first time ) that calculates only hours ( around 15 values ).This data is stored in an array. The user then enters a date and a time which is stored in date data type variable. Here is my problem, I want to add the hours that are stored in the array to the date and time variable to get the respective new date and time.

But I get the following error : "Compiler Error Message: BC30311: Value of type 'Date' cannot be converted to 'Integer'."

Here is my snippet

```
 For i = 0 To 16
ReDim ntra(i)
ntra(i) = ntime2.AddHours(tra(i))
 Next
```

Where, ntra() and tra() are declared as Integers and tra() holds the 'hours' values
       ntime2 is declared as  Date and holds the date and time value entered by the user
       i is declared as an integer

All your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like tra actually holds a date, not an integer as expected. Put a breakpoint on that line and see what it says.

Comment: @Steve: Or the returned value is `DateTime` and it tries to convert it to `Integer`.

Comment: @Steve:  This is how tra() is calculated,                             tra(i) = (Math.Log(counter / co) * (-1 / Val(TextBox2.Text)))           If only there was a way I could convert the numerical value store in the tra() to a date data type. Then probably it would be easy adding up.

Comment: @PatrickHofman is right and his answer he posted is right. I was looking at the wrong side of the equation. You really need to set a breakpoint and see what is happening. It will make much more sense to you once you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `ntime2.AddHours(tra(i))` still yields a `DateTime`. You should declare `ntra` as a `DateTime` instead of an `Integer`.

```
Dim ntra() As DateTime
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried it and was able to run the code but the date just does not get added to the integer values from the array.

Comment: You shouldn't add it to the integers. `DateTime` is not an integer.

Comment: Finally I was able to run the code. Thanks for the guidance